# How do I make hyperlinks without making too much tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

UI'm making my own website wherein it lists all of my games.
But the problem is I have to hard code every game I have, is there something that I can you know not to make so many  tags and html files? thank you.

What I mean is to avoid making too many  tags and html files by making a duplicate and not typing it again and again.

My current code is this:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My games</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Games</h1><br>
  <h3>Games that are made by ME!<br>With dedication and hard work :)</h3><br>
  <hr>
  <a href="square_game.html">Square game</a><br>
  <a href="blocks.html">Blocks</a><br>
  <a href="magestic.html">Magestic</a><br>
  <a href="dave_the_painter.html">Dave The Painter</a><br>
  <a href="paintball_jack.html">Paintball jack</a><br>
  <a href="cat.html">Cat</a><br>
  <a href="cat_sequence.html">Cat: The sequence</a><br>
  <a href="pedro.html">The Blacksmith Named: Pedro</a><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way I can write the same thing but with less code?

Comment: You need a better text editor. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors Generating your HTML from a scripting (or other) language that reads a directory contents or otherwise loops through a list of things can also help. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages

Comment: You are looking for a templating system. While not a templating system itself, I recommend you take a look at PHP to start getting used to the necessary concepts.

Comment: There is a few ways to do this, I would suggest learning something like javascript or if you already know that, react.

Comment: Doing this in front end is not recommended, because this will affect your seo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn about objects, arrays, and loops. Simply put - create an object for each of your games - with the display string and href string for each. Put all the objects into an array, then loop over the array to build your html string. Then insert the string as the innerHTML of the div (or ul).

```js
const games = [
  { link: "square_game.html", display: "Square game"},
  { link: "blocks.html", display: "Blocks"},
  { link: "magestic.html", display: "Magestic"},
  { link: "dave_the_painter.html", display: "Dave The Painter"},
  { link: "paintball_jack.html", display: "Paintball jack"},
  { link: "cat.html", display: "Cat"},
  { link: "cat_sequence.html", display: "Cat: The sequence"},
  { link: "pedro.html", display: "The Blacksmith Named: Pedro"}
]

let list = document.querySelector('#my-games-list');
let listStr = '';
games.forEach(function(game){
  listStr += '<li><a href="'+ game.link+'">'+game.display+'</a></li>';
})

list.innerHTML = listStr;
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My games</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>My Games</h1>
  <h3>Games that are made by ME! With dedication and hard work :)</h3>
  <ul id = "my-games-list"></ul>

</body>
</html>
```